# Cant install AlsaProject

Tags: installation

I need help because I can't install alsaproject utils.
This is the message I get when trying to install:

```
gaston@Small1:~/Descargas/alsa-utils-1.0.27.2$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for msgfmt... no
checking for gmsgfmt... :
checking for xgettext... no
checking for msgmerge... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for ld used by GCC... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for CFPreferencesCopyAppValue... no
checking for CFLocaleCopyCurrent... no
checking for GNU gettext in libc... yes
checking whether to use NLS... yes
checking where the gettext function comes from... libc
checking for cross-compiler... gcc
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for ALSA CFLAGS... 
checking for ALSA LDFLAGS...  -lasound -lm -ldl -lpthread
checking for libasound headers version >= 1.0.27... not present.
configure: error: Sufficiently new version of libasound not found.
gaston@Small1:~/Descargas/alsa-utils-1.0.27.2$
```

Can you help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance. Gaston.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `alsa-utils` from [Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=saucy&section=all&arch=any&keywords=alsa&searchon=names) easily without compiling.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui alsaplayer-alsa alsaplayer-common alsaplayer-daemon alsaplayer-esd alsaplayer-gtk alsaplayer-jack alsaplayer-nas alsaplayer-oss alsaplayer-text alsaplayer-xosd libsox-fmt-alsa alsa-base
```